# How to create a new variable counting duplicate rows based on certain conditions

Tags: r, count, duplicates

I am handling census data using R and it is a very large one with more than ten million cases. I want to count the number of children of each unique household (with its own id) and create a new variable documenting the result.

The census data is stored as a dataframe in R, and it looks like:

(Household ID, an identifier of children or adult)

And rows are like:

```
#Household ID, identifier of children or adult
#1:         1,                               3
#2:         1,                               1
#3:         2,                               1
#4:         3,                               1
......
```

1 stand for adult and 3 for child

What I want is:
(Household ID, an identifier of children or adult, number of children in that household)

```
#Household ID, identifier of children or adult, number of children
#1:         1,                               3,                 1
#2:         1,                               1,                 1
#3:         2,                               1,                 0
#4:         3,                               1,                 1
#5:         3,                               3,                 1
......
```

I tried to use the function length but only came up with a way to do it in a loop, which takes me a week but I don't have that much time now.

Comment: It's ambiguous to me what your data structure looks like. Are those strings, or lists, or separate columns? Could you please share in the text of your question the output of `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out my problem. I have edited the question and see if it is clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count the number of 3's in each household and add it as a new column. After you read the data into R, assuming your dataframe is called `df`, we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, no_of_child := sum(Child_Adult == 3), by = Household_ID]

df
#   Household_ID Child_Adult no_of_child
#1:            1           3           1
#2:            1           1           1
#3:            2           1           0
#4:            3           1           0
```

In base R,

```
df$no_of_child <- with(df, ave(Child_Adult == 3, Household_ID, FUN = sum))
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Household_ID) %>%
  mutate(no_of_child = sum(Child_Adult == 3))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Household_ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Child_Adult = c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to here so.. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, sorry to interrupt. Is it possible to do it when household ID is not one column but two? Say, an unique household can be identified with quarter id and then a household id of that quarter. e.g. for one quarter, there are household id 1 to 6 and then for the next the household id starts from 1 again. I try using c(quarter id, household id) but not working, neither dplyr method or base method.

Comment: @JohnYE Try grouping by two columns in `dplyr`. Try `df %>%
  group_by(Household_ID, quarter_id) %>%
  mutate(no_of_child = sum(Child_Adult == 3))`